# How to get the ERC-20 token balance of an account using etherjs?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, dapp-development, ethers.js

I want to get the ERC-20 token balance of an account using ethers.js. Could you help me?

Comment: What kind of information are you looking for?

Comment: I want to get the token balance of my wallet using ether.js.

Comment: That's more token contract information than it is wallet information.

Comment: I've updated your question.

Comment: Related: you can use [create-eth-app](https://github.com/paulrberg/create-eth-app) to get a boilerplate React/ Vue.js template that contains a script for querying an ERC-20 token balance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
const ethers = require('ethers');
const genericErc20Abi = require(..../.../Erc20.json);
const tokenContractAddress = '0x...';
const provider = ...; (use ethers.providers.InfuraProvider for a Node app or ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum/window.web3) for a React app)
const contract = new ethers.Contract(tokenContractAddress, genericErc20Abi, provider);
const balance = (await contract.balanceOf((await provider.getSigners())[0].address)).toString();
```

This will return the result in wei. If you want to know the exact amount of token with its token name then you need to divide it with its decimal. For example if you want to get USDC amount you need to divide the result by 10^6.

```
const balance = ((await contract.balanceOf((await provider.getSigners())[0].address))/10**6).toString();
```

The final output will be "TokenAmount USDC" (example 10 USDC).

Comment: Could you send me Erc20.json?

Comment: You could find it here: https://ethereumdev.io/abi-for-erc20-contract-on-ethereum/

Comment: I've made some edits in my answer above.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had an error, `provider.getSigners is not a function` What does reason? I am a beginner. Help me.

Comment: Could you try `provider.getSigner()` instead?

Comment: `Could you try provider.getSigner() instead?` What means? I am going to use contractAddress instead of `provider.getSinger()`. Right?

Comment: I meant to replace the method call I have above from:
```const balance = (await contract.balanceOf((await provider.getSigners())[0].address)).toString();```
to
```const balance = (await contract.balanceOf((await provider.getSigner()).address)).toString();
```

Comment: Did the above work?

Comment: I got error as Uncaught (in promise) Error: invalid address or ENS name (argument="name", value=null, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.5.0)
    at Logger.makeError (index.ts:225:1)
    at Logger.throwError (index.ts:237:1)
    at Logger.throwArgumentError (index.ts:241:1)
    at index.ts:120:1
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (index.ts:1:1)

Comment: @RohitMittal Usually when you get this error either the address you're using is wrong or you're connected to the wrong network which makes the "correct" address invalid because it probably does not exist on this network