# How to get the balance of any Token other than ETH?

Tags: balances, ethers.js

I'm using ether.js library and infura as provider, the code works for getting balance of Eth:

```js
const provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider(Provider_network, {
    infura: MY_INFURA_ID
})
const balance = await provider.getBalance(MY_WALLET);
console.log("balance: ", balance.toBigInt())
```

How to get balance of other token in my wallet? For example for token ABC with contact address "0xAbcAbcAbc..."

Comment: your question was already asked here:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/101858/how-to-get-the-erc-20-token-balance-of-an-account-using-etherjs

Comment: FYI, ETH is not a token